# Can both my flag as well as unflag text have different background images?

Tags: 7, flags

I am using the Flag module to flag content and users on my site. In one of the nodes, i have attached a background image to the flag link. On clicking the link, the users also have the ability to unflag it. So on the unflag link i want another background image. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a preprocess function to override the output as a span with classes.

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_flag(&$variables) {
  $flag = &$variables['flag'];
  $action = $variables['action'];
  if ($flag->name == 'drupal_like') {
    if ($action == 'flag') {
      $variables['link_text'] = '<span class="flag flag-heart-light"></span>';
    }
    else{
      $variables['link_text'] = '<span class="flag flag-heart-dark"></span>';
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can target these classes to write your css as David mentioned.

```
.flag-heart-dark{
  background: transparent url('images/flag.png') no-repeat;
}

.flag-heart-light{
  background: transparent url('images/unflag.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: as mentioned in below comments by Jeroen, if I want to use .flag-action and .unflag-action classes with your code, will it be correct like this? `$variables['link_text'] = '<span class="flag flag-action"></span>';
    }
    else{
      $variables['link_text'] = '<span class="flag unflag-action"></span>';` and in css `.flag-action{` and `.unflag-action{`

Comment: That will work @Umair

Comment: How can I use fontawesome icons with it? code plz

Answer (score 1):

If the unflag link has a different CSS class, which it presumably does, you could  set the background image with CSS

e.g, in style.css:

```
.unflag{
  background: transparent url('images/unflag.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: How can one add a CSS class to a flag? I can't find that option at `Structure > Flags > MyFlag`.

Comment: You probably need to target it using the current classes, e.g `.container .flag`

Comment: The correct CSS classes in Drupal 7 are `.flag-action` and `.unflag-action`.